# Laravel ORM select and whereBetween

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have next code:

```
$properties = $properties
->selectRaw('*,'. $this->userCurrency->c_rate .' / c_rate  * p_fixed_price AS 
converted_p_fixed_price');
```

after that I want to sort by this price.

```
 $properties = $properties->whereBetween('converted_p_fixed_price',
     [$request->low_price ,$request->hight_price]
 );
```

But in result i got Column not found: 1054
Please help, how to whereBetween that field in right way?

Comment: problem in your select, what is $this->userCurrency->c_rate property?

Comment: What do you want to do?? your select query is not correct.

Comment: if i make dd($properties->get()); after my select  - in attributes i have   "converted_p_fixed_price" => "70" , i`t counting in right way

Comment: What column not found in error message??

Comment: After second part - message say that converted_p_fixed_price field is not found.

Comment: but after first part i make $properties->first()->converted_p_fixed_price . and it get right result

Comment: Put your entire code in the question plz. What does occur between two queries? When running second part(just before running it) what is output of `$properties->toSql()`?

Comment: nothing more...

Comment: "select distinct *,1.0000 / c_rate  * p_fixed_price AS converted_p_fixed_price from `properties` left join `property_types` as `pt` on `property_type_id` = `pt`.`pt_id` left join `currency` on `currency`.`c_id` = `properties`.`currency_id` where `p_status` = ? and (exists (select * from `users` where `properties`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `deleted_at` is null and `users`.`deleted_at` is null))                                     and that returns good result for me.

Comment: Use `having` instead of `whereBetween`.

Answer (score 1):

As referred [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html) :**An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses to refer to the column, Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined**, so you must use `having` instead of `whereBetween`.

The second part of your code can be something like this:

```
 $properties = $properties
        ->having('converted_p_fixed_price', '>=', $request->low_price)
        ->having('converted_p_fixed_price', '<=' ,$request->hight_price);
```

As you can not use pagination with `having` clauses in Laravel, if you want to paginate results, you can use something like this:

```
$properties = $properties
    ->whereRaw($this->userCurrency->c_rate . ' / c_rate  * p_fixed_price >= ' . $request->low_price)
    ->whereRaw($this->userCurrency->c_rate . ' / c_rate  * p_fixed_price <= ' . $request->hight_price)
    ->paginate($page_length);
```

Comment: Don't forget the upvote and accepting as correct answer!!

Comment: one more question, i can`t use paginate() with having?

Comment: No! you must manually paginate the results. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303815/laravel-orm-select-and-wherebetween/51304197#51304197)